# Gravity forms php code for currency

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I've found this code so that the "€" currency sign is aligned on the left instead of after the product (thats how it's showed in the Netherlands, so €20,00 instead of 20,00€)

This is de code: [GravityForms currency](https://www.pronamic.nl/2012/04/gravity-forms-euro-teken-voor-bedrag/)

But it gives me this error in Wordpress?

syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'

Comment: Can you post the code here?

Comment: Not _can you_, but _you need to_ post the code here.  When that link breaks/goes down/is removed, this question will have no value to future visitors.  **Also**, past the _complete_ error message here, including the portion that indicates what line number.  THEN, indicate in your code that you paste here which line is the line number being reported in the error.  (**Error messages** are super valuable, and tell you super useful info about how to fix the issue).

Comment: As a side-note, the code in that link is not complete / valid.  This portion `"name" =--> __("Euro", "gravityforms")` is invalid, and should simply read `"name" => __("Euro", "gravityforms")`....